# Why can't the file be renamed, while it doesn't have any illegal character in it?

Tags: windows-8.1, rename, filenames

I try to rename a file with a (long) name not including any illegal character, but Windows keeps making error:

[image]

I use Windows 8.1. The name is: `Compare the electrostastic energy between
mutants of HIV1 protease binding to lopinavir`.

Comment: What is your file path? [Possible issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065993/has-windows-7-fixed-the-255-character-file-path-limit)

Comment: That filename makes me feel like an old  man, for wanting to yell at the kids to use short and intutitave filenames with no spaces. I once met a girl who had filled up the entire FAT extended name table for her floppy disk with 3 files, all of which had names that took more room than the filedata itself.

Comment: Your quoted text certainly has a newline character in it (after between). Remove that and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to copy-paste this text: `Compare the electrostastic energy between mutants of HIV1 protease binding to lopinavir`

I think that there has been an invisible illegal character inside your text, a line break maybe

Comment: did You manage to solve the problem? If the answer helped, You can accept it as a solution so it can help other viewers as well. If You solved it using another method, You should answer your own question in a few words.